# Ranges generated with arc4random() are incorrect

Tags: objective-c, random

This is my code:

```
secretPointX = (arc4random() % 600) + 400;
secretPointY = (arc4random() % 350) + 250;
```

I use these as coordinates, and use them for the radius of a circle using pythagoras theorem. My problem is that it doesn't generate random number between the range 400-600 and 250-350. It generates numbers outside the specified range. What is wrong?

Comment: it works correctly. You are using it incorrectly for what you want.

Comment: Don't use such grievously misleading titles. `arc4random()` works just fine. The code that uses it does not.

Comment: sorry but that was like why I was asking. If I knew that it wasn't arc4random that was wrong I wouldn't ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modulo division gives you the remainder of the operation. Simply, when you're using it like this, it gives you a number from 0 through one less than the right-hand operand. You're getting numbers up to 599 and then adding them to 400.

You should be doing this:

```
u_int32_t max = 600;
u_int32_t min = 400;
u_int32_t result = (arc4random % (max - min) + 1) + min;
```

or, better,

```
arc4random_uniform(max - min + 1) + min;
```

Comment: it just gives me a huge number

Comment: You would want `arc4random_uniform(max - min + 1) + min` since `arc4random_uniform` returns values in the range "0 .. (val - 1)".

Comment: @JimmyYXA: Yes, with the caveat that rmaddy just commented about; add 1 to the range or you'll only end up with numbers from 400-599.

Comment: well yes but it still gives me a huge number

Comment: like 7485835. outside the range

Comment: @JimmyYXA: What are the types of `secretPointX` and `secretPointY`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell they are floats

Comment: @JimmyYXA: I thought you were satisfied with the answer since you checked it off. There's no more information to be had from your post; there's something else going on in other code.

Answer (score 3):

You're generating a random number between zero (including) and 600 (excluding) and then adding 400 to it. That will naturally result in a number that's between 400 and 999. Use something like this instead:

```
secretPointX = (arc4random() % 201) + 400;
```

You can also use `arc4random_uniform(201)` to get a random number between zero and 200 without doing a modulo operation.

Comment: Note that the ranges are half-open, so 1000 will never be generated.